# Unable to get correct keyboard input from keyboard buffer in linux

Tags: c++, linux, keyboard-events

I am writing a program that will simply read the keyboard buffer and print the currently pressed key to the terminal. The program will run from the command line without an X server running, so it is important for it to read directly from the device. Using the linux input API I am able to read the key codes, but they are being stored in  the wrong variable (event.value not event.code). Moreover, on some systems I can't seem to get the correct code at all and it just spits out garbage. I have also tried using getch() from the ncurses library, but it doesn't read some special keys like volume up and down. Here is my abbreviated code:

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{   
    int fd = 0;
    char device[PATH_MAX];

    /*
    *
    *This code finds the first keyboard device in /dev/input/by-path/
    *
    */

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir ("/dev/input/by-path/")) != NULL) {
        /* print all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
             if(strstr(ent->d_name, "kbd") != NULL)
             {
                sprintf(device, "/dev/input/by-path/%s", ent->d_name);
             }
        }
        closedir (dir);
    }

    /*
    *
    *This code reads the keyboard buffer and prints the key code
    *
    */

    while(true)
    {
        // Read the key from the keyboard buffer
        int fd1 = 0;
        if((fd1 = open(device, O_RDONLY)) > 0 ) 
        {
            struct input_event event;
            unsigned int key = 0;
            read(fd1, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));
            key = event.value; //seems contrary to documentation, but it works(mostly)

            printf("Key Code: %d\n", key);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `open` in a loop (especially since you don't seem to `close` the file)? Open *once* before you enter the loop to read the input. And always check the result of `read`.

Comment: Well in the original example program I was working off of it said it was important to open a new file descriptor each time to keep from blocking other programs from reading. I just tried it though and it seems to work fine. That's what you get for trusting random people on the internet ig.

Comment: Well you can open it multiple times, but then you must remember to close the file once you're done with it. There's only a limited set of descriptors available for each process.

Comment: Wow. That just fixed the problem. That's kinda embarrassing actually. Thanks  Some programmer dude.